# Deploy .exe with .ini file using ansible

Tags: windows, installation, ansible, ansible-playbook

I have installer.exe with setup.ini file. It installs perfectly. As long as I open installer with double click or cli. When I'm trying to run it remotly installer just ignores .ini file. It doesn't ANY accept params. It's Windows 10 Pro.

Output from win_copy

```
ok: [DESKTOP-123.domain] => {
    "changed": false,
    "checksum": "0...7",
    "dest": "C:\\setup.ini",
    "operation": "file_copy",
    "original_basename": "setup.ini",
    "size": 179,
    "src": "\\\\server\\path\\setup.ini" }
```

```
ok: [DESKTOP-123.domain] => {
    "changed": false,
    "checksum": "2...b",
    "dest": "C:\\Installer.exe",
    "operation": "file_copy",
    "original_basename": "Installer.exe",
    "size": 659712696,
    "src": "server\\path\\Installer.exe" }
```

Installer playbook

```
  - name: Installer
    win_package:
        path: C:\Installer.exe
        product_id: '{1...5}'
        state: present
```

User used by ansible has permission to both files, I can see Installer.exe running im Task Manager, but it doesn't really work since settings are in this .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what helps is adding the /install argument to disable ini file mapping.

Try to run the win_package task like this:

```
- name: Installer
  win_package:
    path: C:\Installer.exe
    product_id: '{1...5}'
    arguments: /install
```

That is similar to the first example of the [win_package documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_package_module.html#examples).

On the Microsoft documentation page for [changing installation modes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/change-user) you can see a note next to the "/install" parameter:

> Disables .ini file mapping to the home directory. All .ini files are read and written to the system directory. You must disable .ini file mapping when installing applications on a Remote Desktop Session Host server.

Hope this helps.